# Overriding toString() causing null pointer in grails domain class

Tags: grails, nullpointerexception

So when I override the toString() method using the method below (the same way I use in almost every one of my other Domain classes across many projects), it causes a null pointer when creating an instance of this object. Removing the toString() fixes this error. No clue why. :(

```
class Vertical {

    String name

    static constraints = {
        name(nullable: true)
    }

    @Override
    String toString() {
        return name
    }
}
```

Comment: Wild guess: grails calls some method on returned `toString` object. On instantiation `name` is null, so it tries to call `null.someMethod()` causing a NullPointerException. For what purpose do you need `toString` method overriden?

Comment: put up some code that references the created instance. the problem is probably there

Comment: def lol = new Vertical()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would be a little bit more defensive and go with:

```
    @Override
    String toString() {
        return (name ?: "")
    }
```

Just to make sure not to send back nulls, since the toString ought to be printable.

Comment: Yeah, I went with this (well, I didn't have the 'return '). Still want to know why grails doesn't like it so much ;p